# How to stop Jquery UI Draggable Div from changing dragged position after a sibling Div's content is changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have HTML markup, shown simplified below:

```
<div id='A'>
    <div id='B'>
        ...
    </div>
    <div id='C'>
         ....
    </div>
</div>
```

All divs have absolute positioning with `div#C` as a draggable div with `appendTo` set to body as in:

```
$('#C').draggable({appendTo: "body"})
```

After I drag this div to some position, say above `div#b`, and then regenerate through Ajax the content of `div#b` which changes its size(not the content of `div#c`), `div#c` loses its dragged position. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample demo or fiddle?

Comment: @Irvin Dominin aka Edward Its a lot of code but the above is a simplified form of what's going on.

Comment: @Samir sounds like its a css trouble since the divs will have `relative position` and B is resized, a fiddle is of great help for us to see what's happening in detail

Comment: @G.Mendes That's my question really. What "position" should be set on the different divs to ensure that Div#C's dragged position does not change after Div B's size changes.